# Can't build index for solr/haystack: unknown field 'django_id'

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to follow along the haystack tutorial.  I run into an error when I run manage.py rebuild index

I get the following error:

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
/Users/heri0n/python_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py:808: RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime (2013-04-07 16:14:15.481145) while time zone support is active.
  RuntimeWarning)
Indexing 1 notes.
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">6</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=haystacktester.note.3] unknown field 'django_id'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
```

I did run manage.py build_solr_schema > ~/solr-4.2.1/example/solr/conf/schema.xml

I had to create the conf directory manually as it did not exist.  I noticed the tutorial uses Solr 3 while I'm on 4.  Did the location of the conf dir change perhaps?

Comment: Check your `schema.xml` for a field called `django_id`. What version of Haystack are you using? If 2.0 Haystack has removed the django_id parameter so that might be whats causing troubles.

Comment: I'm experimenting the same issue, im using Haystack 2.0 beta version, and when i run build_sorl_schema, the xml built has two fields django_ct and django_id, what should i do with them? What's the correct solution?

Comment: What is the correct django_id for Haystack 2.*?

Comment: Look at the NEB answer. It is perfect. It is because you are using Sorl 4.x, not 3.5 like the haystack documentation example. So you have to make some adaptation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with the Solr (haystack document use v3.5.0, here you may be using the latest) not finding the configuration file. These 3 steps worked for me

- Place the schema in solr-x.y.z/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
- In the schema change stopwords_en.txt to lang/stopwords_en.txt
- Add the version field (as mentioned below) to the schema in the fields section

  ```
  <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
  ```

For more information check out the same discussion in [GitHub](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/878)

Comment: Works fine with this steps. Why do all the documentation say solr-x.y.z/example/solr/conf/schema.xml path?

Comment: With solr 4.10.3 adding *lang/* prefix to *stopwords_en.txt* actually cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

This is more of a comment, but due to my lack of points I am unable to comment...

Has anyone figure out a soltuion to this? I'm having the exact same problem. The field is being created in `schema.xml` as such:

```
<field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

I have restarted Solr (multiple times), and I am 100% positive my schema.xml code is correct. What the heck is going on here?

EDIT: I switched to Elasticsearch and have no problems. However, I'm sure others out there would find help to this question useful.

Answer (score 1):

I had to clone the haystack source code and do some hacks as follows :

In the /haystack/management/commands/build_solr_schema.py , I commented `DJANGO_ID` in the `build_context()` func.
Then in `/haystack/templates/search_configuration/solr.xml` , I replaced `{{ DJANGO_ID }}` with `"django_id"` and everything worked ok.

I think the `{{DJANGO_ID}}` is not being replaced with `"django_id"` when you generate `schema.xml`.