# django-haystack error when running "./manage.py rebuild_index

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am getting the below TypeError when running:

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

My current setup is Solr 4.8.1, django-haystack 2.1.0, Django 1.6.2, and Python 3.4.0.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Here is the error thread:

```
ERROR:root:Error updating blog using default 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 221, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 267, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py", line 68, in update
    self.conn.add(docs, commit=commit, boost=index.get_field_weights())
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 779, in add
    return self._update(m, commit=commit, waitFlush=waitFlush, waitSearcher=waitSearcher)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 387, in _update
    return self._send_request('post', path, message, {'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'})
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 318, in _send_request
    error_message = self._extract_error(resp)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 397, in _extract_error
    reason, full_html = self._scrape_response(resp.headers, resp.content)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 467, in _scrape_response
    full_html = full_html.replace('\n', '')
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 16, in handle
    call_command('update_index', **options)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 159, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 195, in handle
    return super(Command, self).handle(*items, **options)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 385, in handle
    label_output = self.handle_label(label, **options)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 221, in handle_label
    self.update_backend(label, using)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 267, in update_backend
    do_update(backend, index, qs, start, end, total, self.verbosity)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/update_index.py", line 89, in do_update
    backend.update(index, current_qs)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/haystack/backends/solr_backend.py", line 68, in update
    self.conn.add(docs, commit=commit, boost=index.get_field_weights())
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 779, in add
    return self._update(m, commit=commit, waitFlush=waitFlush, waitSearcher=waitSearcher)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 387, in _update
    return self._send_request('post', path, message, {'Content-type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'})
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 318, in _send_request
    error_message = self._extract_error(resp)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 397, in _extract_error
    reason, full_html = self._scrape_response(resp.headers, resp.content)
  File "/Users/aaron/Documents/virtualenvs/three/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pysolr.py", line 467, in _scrape_response
    full_html = full_html.replace('\n', '')
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
```

Comment: Hello, Could you show the next files: `project/search_indexes.py` and `project/templates/search/indexes/blog.txt` ? And also the models you're trying to index ? You have to understand is little difficult to help you with the information you gave of the issue

Comment: I've a similar issue? Have You solved it? @Liarez, can You help me somehow?

Comment: @Opal I never solved it.  I changed projects, so didn't spend the time to find out what the answer is.  Please post it though if you find out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a problem with `django_id`. What helped me is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868052/cant-build-index-for-solr-haystack-unknown-field-django-id) question. I did the following things:

- Place the schema in solr-x.y.z/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml
- Add the version field (as mentioned below) to the schema in the *fields* section:

```
<field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```